# Can you fish in Lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I understand there would little point to it, lava isn't exactly a hospitable environment for any kind of fish able mob...

What I was wondering was can you actually cast a line out into lava? Would the lure stay out in the lava like it does in water? Or would it just burn? What happens?

I attempted to find something about it, but everything is purely about what might happen if you use a fishing rod to drag mobs through water or lava. There is nothing about actually casting the line into a pool of lava.

Comment: did you try it? (peaceful nether trip)

Comment: Really do you think there are fishes in LAVA?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort...

Comment: Wouldent the fishes burn to death? I tried fishing myself and found nothing. Waste of 1 hour! (Yes, I acually tried for that long)

Comment: Umm... Ben... Rods only react when attached to mobs or thrown into a **Water** block.

Comment: @TheIdiotGamer I know for a fact that fishing in lava does not return anything. However the interaction between a fishing rod and lava is very odd (as I have described below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, as Johonn and Finn Rayment suggested in the comments above, lava does not interact properly with the fishing rod. It does not burn the lure, and it just (appears) to sink to the bottom of the lava pool, unlike when fishing in water, it will float.

*It does not cause any damage to the rod at all*, while casting onto dry land, or any other mob or entity *will* cause damage to the rod.

This was tested in 1.8.1, in both Survival and Creative, (there was no difference between the gamemodes) though I am unaware of the behaviour in earlier versions. It does seem bugged however, due to the odd behaviours I described above.

[image: After 10 casts, no damage to the Rod.]

Comment: This is quite a common practice actually. The fact that you can even answer your own question before you post it allows for this. The only reason that this Q&A moght stand out from the rest is the fact that the question is asking about an obscure situation within the game, but the fact that this has recieved upvotes on both the question *and* answer is proof enough that there is nothing wrong with either.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek This is actually the kind of reason self-answering exists. There are deleted "answers" here that indicate other people wondered about the same thing, and the question has a decent number of votes and views. Ben asked, and then worked to figure it out. I see no problem with it existing, nor do I think it's "awful".

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Ironically or not, comments like that are completely unnecessary. Intent is sometimes hard to read in text (smiley face or not). Please refrain from leaving comments like that in the future.